# BDE não conecta ao usuário Sysdba

Tags: delphi, firebird

Estou passando por algum problema com meu BDE que não sei ainda direito o que é, por algum motivo ele não conecta no banco com o usuário|senha padrão do firebird. Eu conecto o mesmo banco pelo ibexpert e funciona, mas pelo BDE não funciona, o que pode ser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri o problema era o `GDS32.dll` que estava na minha pasta do sysWOW64 que estava com uma versão diferente. Apaguei a mesma e reinstalei o firebird e deu certo (lembrando de marcar opção para copiar `GDS32.dll` para pasta do sistema)